# Different ways to handle triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

First table represents the `Nurse` and second one is representing `MedicalRecords` she is in charge of. You can find both of the columns from `Nurse` table in the `MedicalRecords` table where the column `IDNurse` is `foreign key` and the second column is there because of `denormalization`.

```
Nurse:
┌─────────┬───────────┐
│ IDNurse │ NurseName │
├─────────┼───────────┤
│ 1       │ name1     │
│ 2       │ name2     │
└─────────┴───────────┘
MedicalRecords:
┌──────┬────────────┬──────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ IDMR │ Date       │ Note │ IDNurse │ NurseName │
├──────┼────────────┼──────┼─────────┼───────────┤
│ 1    │ 12/11/2017 │ /    │ 1       │ name1     │
└──────┴────────────┴──────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

I have implemented two triggers on `MedicalRecords` where one is getting `NurseName` upon inserting new record (according to `IDNurse`) and another one is there to restrict update of `NurseName` column:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[RESTRICT]
   ON  [dbo].[MedicalRecords] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF UPDATE (NurseName)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RAISERROR('You are not allowed to update that column from this table!', 16, -1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN
END
```

There is also one trigger implemented on `Nurse` which triggers upon updating column `NurseName` and updates the same column in `MedicalRecords`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NurseName-UPDATE] 
   ON  [dbo].[Nurse]
   AFTER UPDATE AS 
   IF UPDATE (NurseName)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    ALTER TABLE DBO.MedicalRecords DISABLE TRIGGER RESTRICT
    UPDATE DBO.MedicalRecords SET NurseName = (SELECT NurseName
                                                    FROM Nurse 
                                                    WHERE MedicalRecords.IDNurse = (SELECT IDNurse FROM Nurse))
    ALTER TABLE DBO.MedicalRecords ENABLE TRIGGER RESTRICT
END
```

1. Is there any other way to accomplish updating of `NurseName` when it is updated in `Nurse` without disabling and enabling `RESTRICT` trigger in `MedicalRecords`?
2. Is there any situation where if some problem happens in the middle of it, `RESTRICT` trigger would stay disabled? How could I be sure that `RESTRICT` trigger is always enabled, for example something like `finally` block in `try-catch`?

Comment: OLTP tables should be normalized. Normalization is there to get rid of duplicating info across the tables.

Comment: @sepupic I know that, but this is a project for my university where I have to demonstrate the process of `denormalization`

Comment: You should demonstrate denormalization used for make life easier, not more difficult. Create 10 tables for DWH and demonstrate how the query from one denormalized table is faster than a query with 9 joins between 10 table

Comment: The code I have posted is just an improvisation of the real code I am using. I don't really have table with two columns and only two table total. But I still need help to avoid enabling/disabling triggers

Comment: If you need to disable/enable any trigger from other trigger it's a BAD design to be rewritten

Comment: check my 4th solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree,that this is not proper example of denormalization.This is invalid database design on the name of denormalization.

Still you have interesting problem.both your question is good.

Your second question is easy,I try to find solution of first problem later on.

> Is there any situation where if some problem happens in the middle of
>   it, RESTRICT trigger would stay disabled? How could I be sure that
>   RESTRICT trigger is always enabled, for example something like finally
>   block in try-catch?

you can begin try and transaction inside proc

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.triggerTest ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, someData VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NEWID() )
GO

ALTER TRIGGER dbo.itrg_triggerTest  ON dbo.triggerTest
FOR INSERT
AS

--SELECT @@PROCID, OBJECT_NAME( @@PROCID ) 

--SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME( parent_id ) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME( parent_id ) tableName FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = @@PROCID
select 1/0
GO





ALTER proc test1
as
begin
begin try
begin tran
INSERT INTO dbo.triggerTest DEFAULT VALUES
COMMIT
end try
begin catch
print 'hi'
 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
ROLLBACK
end catch
end
go

exec test1

select * from triggerTest

DROP TABLE dbo.triggerTest
GO
```

Since there is divided by 0 error inside trigger,proc catch block will always fire then you can enable the trigger code.So error occur because of anything you enable trigger inside catch block.

`Second solution` is to drop trigger idea and define foreign key constraint on delete on update cascade.
for this you have to define composite primary key on nurseid and nursename on nurse table which may not be acceptable to you.

Otherwise it work fine

see,

```
create table nurse(IDNurse int identity(1,1) ,NurseName varchar(50) not null
,primary key (IDNurse,NurseName))
insert into nurse VALUES
('name1'),('name2')

create table MedicalRecords(IDMR int identity(1,1),Dates date, Note varchar(50),IDNurse int ,NurseName varchar(50)
,FOREIGN KEY (IDNurse,NurseName) REFERENCES nurse(IDNurse,NurseName) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE  )
insert into MedicalRecords VALUES
('12/11/2017','/',1,'name1')

--drop table MedicalRecords

--According to current example

--this fail
--update MedicalRecords set NurseName='name3',IDNurse=1
--this pass
--update MedicalRecords set NurseName='name1',IDNurse=1
--this pass
--update MedicalRecords set NurseName='name2',IDNurse=2
--this fail
--update MedicalRecords set NurseName='name22',IDNurse=2

--this pass and medicalrecord is auto updated
--update Nurse set NurseName='name3' where IDNurse=1

--disadvantage primary key (IDNurse,NurseName) may not be accepttable

Is there any other way to accomplish updating of NurseName when it is updated in Nurse without disabling and enabling RESTRICT trigger in MedicalRecords?
```

I think you can do this using [TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trigger-nestlevel-transact-sql).I am not very expert in using it so thourouhgly test it.

Drop previous example,drop table,drop trigger.

```
--drop table nurse
create table nurse(IDNurse int identity(1,1) ,NurseName varchar(50) not null
)
insert into nurse VALUES
('name1'),('name2')

create table MedicalRecords(IDMR int identity(1,1),Dates date, Note varchar(50),IDNurse int ,NurseName varchar(50)
 )
insert into MedicalRecords VALUES
('12/11/2017','/',1,'name1')

--drop table MedicalRecords

CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[NurseName-UPDATE] 
   ON  [dbo].[Nurse]
   AFTER UPDATE AS 
   IF UPDATE (NurseName)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --ALTER TABLE DBO.MedicalRecords DISABLE TRIGGER RESTRICT
    UPDATE MR
    set NurseName=i.NurseName
    from DBO.MedicalRecords MR
    inner join inserted i on mr.IDNurse=i.IDNurse

    --ALTER TABLE DBO.MedicalRecords ENABLE TRIGGER RESTRICT
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[RESTRICT]
   ON  [dbo].[MedicalRecords] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF UPDATE (NurseName)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL( OBJECT_ID('NurseName-UPDATE')))=0)
    BEGIN
    --SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME( parent_id ) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME( parent_id ) tableName FROM sys.triggers 
    --WHERE object_id = @@PROCID
    RAISERROR('You are not allowed to update that column from this table!', 16, -1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Ready to test !!

```
--This one fail
update MedicalRecords set NurseName='name1',IDNurse=1

-- This one pass
update Nurse set NurseName='name3' where IDNurse=1
```

> 4th solution,

This one is perfect,easy and will work across all version.Here idea is to allow update MedicalRecord table,but if that record do not exists in nurse table then rollback.

```
--drop table nurse
create table nurse(IDNurse int identity(1,1) ,NurseName varchar(50) not null
)
insert into nurse VALUES
('name1'),('name2')


create table MedicalRecords(IDMR int identity(1,1),Dates date, Note varchar(50),IDNurse int ,NurseName varchar(50)
 )
insert into MedicalRecords VALUES
('12/11/2017','/',1,'name1')

--drop table MedicalRecords

CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[NurseName-UPDATE] 
   ON  [dbo].[Nurse]
   AFTER UPDATE AS 
   IF UPDATE (NurseName)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE MR
    set NurseName=i.NurseName
    from DBO.MedicalRecords MR
    inner join inserted i on mr.IDNurse=i.IDNurse


END
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[RESTRICT]
   ON  [dbo].[MedicalRecords] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
IF UPDATE (NurseName)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if not exists(SELECT nursename from dbo.nurse n where exists(select nursename from inserted i 
    where n.nursename=i.nursename and n.IDNurse=i.IDNurse ))
    BEGIN

    RAISERROR('You are not allowed to update that column from this table!', 16, -1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
    RETURN
END
GO

--This one pass
update MedicalRecords set NurseName='name1'where IDNurse=1

--This one fail
update MedicalRecords set NurseName='name1' where IDNurse=2

--this one fail
update MedicalRecords set NurseName='name2'
```

Comment: Thanks! Since there is a situation in which this happens, I should avoid enabling and disabling trigger. Now, how can I do it, but still keep the behavior it has now, where trigger does not allow updating field from different table, but only from table where that column was mainly created in?

Comment: Wow, now that is commitment! Thank you, you have helped me a lot! That solves my problem and I'm gonna use last solution as basic for building the rest of my project.